# Intersection of locally closed subschemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $S$ be a Noetherian scheme and $Y,Z$ two locally closed subschemes.

What is the scheme theoretic intersection of $Y$ and $Z$. I am asking because in Mumford's "Lectures on curves on an algebraic surface" page 59. He defines it as, I quote, topologically it is the intersection $Supp(Y) \cap Supp(Z)$ and you take the scheme structure to be the sum of the ideals defining $Y$ and $Z$.

Am I correctly understanding that this means the following : cover $S$ by opens $U_i$ such that $Z\cap U_i$ and $Y\cap U_i$ are closed defined by ideals $I_i$ and $J_i$ and define $W_i$ to be the closed subscheme of $U_i$ defined by $I_i+J_i$ and then define $W$, the scheme intersection of $Y$ and $Z$ to be the glueing of the $W_i$'s ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I took $I_i$ and $J_i$ to be quasi-coherent sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_{U_i}$ ideals so I don't think I need to suppose that $U_i$ is affine right ?. My problems comes from the fact that $Y$ and $Z$ are only locally closed so I don't think $I_Y$ and $I_Z$ are defined globally right ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant closed subschemes. I prefer not to pronounce myself on locally closed subschemes which are neither closed nor open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition there exist a pair of open subschemes $Y_0$ and $Z_0$ such that: $Y$ and $Z$ are closed subschemes of $Y_0$ and $Z_0$, respectively; without loss of generality (*wlog* for short) one can assume that $Y_0$ and $Z_0$ are the biggest ones with this property ([B] Remark 7.3.12).

The scheme theoretic intersection $S_0=Y_0\times_SZ_0$ is exactly $Y_0\cap Z_0$ (cfr. [B] Lemma 7.2.5) considered as open subscheme of $S$!

Wlog, one can assume that $S_0,Y_0,Z_0,Y$ and $Z$ are affine; one needs to compute $Y\times_{Y_0}S_0$ and $Z\times_{Z_0}S_0$, that is:
\begin{equation*}
S_0=Spec(A_0),\,Y_0=Spec(B_0),\,Z_0=Spec(C_0),\,Y=Spec(B),\,Z_0=Spec(C)
\end{equation*}
where $B=B_{0\displaystyle/I_0}$ and $C=C_{0\displaystyle/J_0}$ for some ideals $I_0$ and $J_0$ of $B_0$ and $C_0$, respectively (see [B] Lemma 7.3.8).

From all this:
\begin{gather*}
Y\times_{Y_0}S_0=Spec\left(B_{0\displaystyle/I_0}\otimes_BA_0\right)=Spec\left(A_{0\displaystyle/I}\right),\\
Z\times_{Z_0}S_0=Spec\left(C_{0\displaystyle/J_0}\otimes_CA_0\right)=Spec\left(A_{0\displaystyle/J}\right),\\
\left(Y\times_{Y_0}S_0\right)\times_{S_0}\left(Z\times_{Z_0}S_0\right)=Spec\left(A_{0\displaystyle/I}\otimes A_{0\displaystyle/J}\right)=\\
=Spec\left(A_{0\displaystyle/I+J}\right)=Y\cap Z,
\end{gather*}
where $I$ and $J$ are obvious; this last one scheme is exacly the scheme theoretic intersection of $Y$ and $Z$ over $S_0$; but by universal property of fibre product of schemes, it is $Y\cap Z$ as affine $S$-scheme.

Gluing togheter these affine $S$-schemes, one has that the support of scheme theoretic intersection over $S$ of $Y$ and $Z$ is $Y\cap Z$.

---

[B] S. Bosch (2013) *Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra*, Springer

Comment: I have my doubts. We can choose $Y_{0}$ to be the largest open subset of S such that $Y$ is closed in $Y_{0}$. Unless we have $Z_{0}\subseteq Y_{0}$, me must have that $S_{0}$ strictly contains $Y_{0}$, and it follows that $Y$ cannot be topologically closed in $S_{0}$, so in particular, $Y$ cannot be a closed subscheme of $S_{0}$.

Comment: Why does the largest open subset of $S$ s.t. $Y$ is closed exist? And, if it exists and I call it $Y_0$; I repeat the same reasoning for $Z$ and I find $Z_0$. By a topological reason, one has $Y_0=Z_0$. Indeed, there exists $Y_1,Z_1$ closed in $S$ such that $Y=Y_0\cap Y_1$ and $Z=Z_0\cap Z_1$ are closed in $Y_0$ and $Z_0$, respectively. But $Y\cup Z$ is closed in $Y_0\cup Z_0$, which is open in $S$. By hypothesis: $Y_0=Z_0$.

Comment: About the largest open subset: Let $Y=U\cap \overline{Y}$ for $U\subseteq S$ open.  If $Y_{0}= S\backslash(\overline{Y}\backslash Y)$, then $Y_{0}$ is open since $\overline {Y}\backslash Y= (X\backslash U)\cap \overline{Y}$, $Y$ is closed in $Y_{0}$ for we can write it as $Y=Y_{0}\cap \overline{Y}$. Now assume $W$ is some open subset of $S$ in which $Y$ is closed, then $Y=\overline{Y}\cap W$ and hence $W$ cannot contain any point in $\overline{Y}\backslash {Y}$. It follows that $W$ is contained in $Y_{0}$.

Comment: Maybe there is some input on the topology of schemes that I am missing. However, if you only assume $X$ to be a topological space without any further properties, it it possible to find counterexamples to one of your arguments by taking $Y$ a closed subset of $S$ (and hence $Y_{0}=S$ and $Y_{0}\cup Z_{0}=S$) and $Z$ some locally closed but not closed subset of $S$ containing $Y$. Then $Y\cup Z\subseteq Y_{0}\cup Z_{0}$ is not closed.

Comment: I find my mistake: my original $S_0$ is an open subscheme of $S$, **but** I can't state that $Y_0$ and $Z_0$ are open **subschemes** of it. Now I fix all these. Thank you.